# Should I redeclare methods from an informal protocol in the interface file of my subclass?

Tags: objective-c, protocols, categories

I have a class, which is a subclass of `NSObject`. `NSObject` has an informal protocol (category) `NSComparisonMethods`. Now, when I need to implement the methods from that protocol in my subclass, should I redeclare them in the interface file of that subclass, or it is optional because my superclass already has them declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface is a contract between implementation and user. A subclass inhertis this contract. So, indeed, there seems to be no reason to signal the subclass' implementation by re-mention the method in the interface.

However, to me this was always to formal. The semantics of a method can change in a subclass without infringing the contract. I always redeclare every overwrting method in a subclass.

In your case, when `NSObject` does not implement the methods, redeclaring is definitely the right way, because semantics really change.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. So are you saying, that I should redeclare them in my subclasses of `NSObject` because in them the meaning of the methods can change (for one subclass the meaning of `isEqualTo` can differ from the meaning of the same method in another one)?

Comment: For some methods it is hard to imagine, that the semantics can change. However, in your case it would, because I think you will implement a "real" `-isEqualTo:` instead of `NSObject`'s "`-isIdenticalTo:`"-Implementation. So I would mention it in the header by redeclaring it. And since I do not like to think a long time for such situations, I decided to redeclare overwritten methods in nearly all cases. But this is opinion based.

Comment: BTW: From your code, you should use and implement `-isEqual:` and/or `-isEqualTo…:` instead of `-isEqualTo:`, because the latter one is intended for scripting.